# What are the alternatives to SAS formats in python?

Tags: python, sqlite, sas

I'm trying to do a task in python which I normally do in SAS, in order to learn python. My work is in official statistics and I'm supposed to make some tables on employment by age group and gender. So far data has been exported from SAS as csv and imported to sqlite. The problem I'm faced with now is to aggregate age into age groups.

The variables in the dataset is age and gender, and in SAS I would normally use a format to recode age into age group. Python does not seem to have an equivalent to SAS formats. I think the best way to handle formats would be to import them as a separate table in sqlite (containing age and age group as variables), and join the two tables based on age as key. However, the values in the sas format is ranges (start and stop) and I'm unsure about how to populate the age group table in a clever way. With this small format the recoding could be done by a case statement in sql, but the table approach would be much more useful for other formats which are bigger, e.g. the Standard for Industrial Classification (SIC 2007). Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to join tables with arbitrary conditions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Data(Age, [...]);
CREATE TABLE AgeGroups(AgeGroup, Min, Max);
...
SELECT AgeGroups.AgeGroup,
       Data.[...],
FROM Data
JOIN AgeGroups ON Data.Age BETWEEN AgeGroups.Min AND AgeGroups.Max;
```

(This has nothing to do with Python.)